# What is the fundamental meaning of max worker threads in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using sql 2019 on 8cpu machine, and as per this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15#Recommendations) the default number of max worker threads are:576

What does this number signify?

For example - assuming max DOP is 1 (no parallelism), does this mean that the SQL server will support query request from 576 clients concurrently?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the fundamental meaning of max worker threads in SQL server?

It means what it states, this is the (soft) maximum number of threads that SQL Server will create and use.

> For example - assuming max DOP is 1 (no parallelism), does this mean that the SQL server will support query request from 576 clients concurrently?

It encompasses all threads, not just those that run queries.

Comment: What happens if the max limit is reached and a new query arrives?

Comment: @variable That depends if there is an available worker or not. If there is, it'll run, if there isn't then it'll wait - assuming it wasn't a new login.